# In DB2 Database, How to find out the actual storage size of data in varchar column?

Tags: db2

I am new to DB2, and I am looking for a function like memory_size(COLUMN_NAME) to return the number of bytes occupied by that column of a particular row.

**Example:** I am having a column named **'Address'** of **VARCHAR(50)** datatype & data is stored as **'Fountain Street, ZIP-12345'**, the function should return the memory occupied by these 26 characters, **not** the  total column size **nor** the length of data.

Thank you!

Comment: `length()` can also handle multi-byte character sets (for single byte character sets the length **is** the "memory occupied". See the manual: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000818.html

Comment: Parameter 'OCTET' was helpful. It gives byte count. Also got OCTET_LENGTH function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the precision of a column, via the catalog (length will query the database catalog). However, the real storage size vary.

You cannot infer something like

```
cardinality * (leght(column1) + lenght(column2) + ...) = occupied storage
```

There are many other facts that affect the storage.

Also, the title of the question is storage size (it seems tablespace -> container), but in the body you are talking about memory (bufferpool) and those things are different in databases.

What do you mean by "memory occupied"? The column precision or the storage usage?

Comment: I wanted to find out the actual number of bytes used to store the data. Not the length. See my example given in the question.

Comment: It depends. If compression is activated, then you cannot know how much space your data occupy. Also, there is a lot of overhead at page size, and DB2 does not allocate space for a single row, but for extents. So what to you want to know?